# How to make a sliding effect - JQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I've made a simple slider by Just adding an active class which changes the display type from none to block.

```
.slide.active {
    display: block;
}

.slide {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

See my solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/6dncwtcu/

Is there a way to make the pictures slide in and out like here: http://www.jssor.com/ or is my solution not suitable for that effect.

Please keep in mind that I don't want to use any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add positioning to each slide, and then animate to the position that you want when a slide is active. I've updated your fiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/6dncwtcu/3/

I've added the following CSS to your `.slide`

```
left: 100%;
position: absolute;
transition: all 200ms;
```

And this to your `.active`

```
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
```

By positioning the slides absolute, you can push them to be outside of the container, and then use your active class to make a slide be at the start of the container again. The `transition` will change how quickly it will animate between slides, and the `z-index` will make sure the active slide is always on top.

Comment: Hi Sam, that goes in the right direction, but it doesn't look smooth since the picture disappears in the same direction which the next one is coming from.

Comment: You could alter your script to add classes to the "before" and "after" slides, which you could include extra css for this kind of thing. Ex: the `.before` would have `left: -100%`